# Floating Action Button render issue on pre-lollipop versions

Tags: android

I have put FAB in my app & it works fine.But it looks weird on pre-lollipop versions. It has got some ugly shadow on top of FAB. This is my FAB tag

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_up"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/coordinatorLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:rippleColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/transperant_black"
        app:elevation="5dp"/>
```

[FAB looks like this on Android 4.2.2 & Android 4.4.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uXnK.png)

Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on pre lollipop devices,
I used these lines of code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/FABinstance"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:rippleColor="@color/transparent_black_hex_5"
    android:src="@drawable/editicon"
    android:backgroundTint="#086428"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

and I had another problem with FAB backgroundtint which I handled programatically:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Build.VERSION_CODES.Lollipop)
                {
                    FABinstance.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Color.ParseColor("#086428"));
                }
```

[image: FAB buttons on pre lollipop devices using android support design library]